# The object is to set off an alarm when the flow of water stops or drastically decreases using a Hall effect flow sensor

Tags: sensor, flow-sensor

I have plumbed a flow sensor similar to [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Water-flow-sensor-flowmeter-Hall-flow-sensor-Water-control-DN15-1-30L-min/191740085353?hash=item2ca4998469:g:1SAAAOSw4UtWSqc6) in the salt water line on my boat between the sea strainer and the suction pump for engine cooling over a 'salt to fresh water' heat exchanger.

When the incoming water flow stops, say, due to a blocked sea suction, or the pump impeller fails, the water flow will diminish to a large extent and the Hall effect sensor should than operate a relay which in turn sets off a high pitch 12V buzzer alarm.

While the sensor is rotating the pulses it generates are used to keep the alarm in the OFF state.

I have built a circuit from a diagram, I found online, but it keeps blowing the transistors.

Can anyone please suggest a working circuit: only on 12V DC.
The diagram should have a linear potentiometer to set a minimum flow rate.

Comment: Realistically you probably want a low-end MCU comparing the setpoint and *somewhat filtered* actual situation, and driving a simple piezo-type alarm.  But in terms of the question asked, no one can explain the failure of the past attempt without its details, and doing a clean sheet design is "too broad" for the mission of this site.

Comment: Please show us a schematic of the circuit that you built.

Comment: Ebay link is broken

Comment: @mhaselup - Hi, That link is broken because the question is a copy & paste of where it was previously asked on the [All About Circuits forum](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/how-to-wire-up-a-flow-sensor-with-hall-effect-to-operate-a-12v-relay.172458/), where the full link isn't *displayed* - so a copy & paste of what is displayed only captures a shortened version :-(  I will fix the link in the question.

Comment: proximitysensor123 - Hi, The thread where you previously posted this on the [All About Circuits forum](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/how-to-wire-up-a-flow-sensor-with-hall-effect-to-operate-a-12v-relay.172458/) has 134 posts! Personally I don't think it's fair on readers here, to potentially duplicate so much work by asking the question from scratch & not mention what has been learned so far. IMHO more disclosure and your analysis of previous effort is needed, to avoid wasting time. The lack of full disclosure will put off some readers, but *perhaps* someone might help. Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson OP has not supplied a schematic and the link to the previous question on the All About Circuits forum requires a login to view the schematic there. That's expecting a lot of running around to even be in a position to think about an answer. Those who ask questions should at least put in the effort to match the effort they expect from others.